# how to add a new field in row based on some value match on dropdown selection

Tags: html, reactjs

I have dropdown in the form. based on selecting the dropdown value if it matches for a specific value i need to show a fiels/lable beside to the dropdown. I took a form in side i wrote like

```
    <div className='row'>
    <div> <label ....>
<select
       name="trnType"
       id="trnType"
       .......
       onChange={event => {values.trnType = event.target.value;}}
       defaultValue={values.trnType}
>
{trnType.map((def, key)=>(
<option key={def.value} value={def.value}>
 <def.label>
</option>
))}
</select>
</label>
</div>
    <div> field shuld display based on value match in above drop down</div>
    </div>
```

any one please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You have to have state. If we talk about the function component.

```
const MyForm = () => {
   const [selectBoxValue, setSelectBoxValue] = useState(here place 2 options)

   return <div className='row'>
             <select onChange={(e) => setSelectBoxValue(e.target.value)}> 
                <option>{selectBoxValue[1]}</option>
                <option>{selectBoxValue[1]}</option>
             </select>
             {selectBoxValue === firstOption 
                  ? <div> some value </div>
                  : <div> another value </div>
          </div>
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am using <select> for dropdown. these same way i can do in the select too. please check my question i have updated. try type define as const trnType = {'a', 'b', 'c'}